# what's mean of "打的"？ How to understand "的"

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context

When I need a taxi, I need to say “打的” instead of "打车"。

So what is the meaning of "的"？How to understand "的"?

When can I use it?

Comment: 打的 (coll.) to take a taxi
to go by taxi, 的 dī
coll. cab，shortened from 的士，also 的哥 （＂的姐＂）taxi driver

Comment: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/8504/loanwords-with-chinese-equivalents/19598#19598

Comment: Chinese words from Hong Kong affects mainland China, e.g., bus is translated to 客车/客車 in mainland before but 巴士 in Hong Kong, gradually the words 长途客车/長途客車 in mainland China now change to 长途大巴/長途大巴 or 长途巴士/長途巴士. We say 叫出租 or 叫出租车/叫出租車 in spoken language before, but now we say 打车/打車 or 打的 commonly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can say "打车". Whether to use "打的" or "打车" might be only personal/regional preference.

Here 的 is pronounced as di1<sup>[1]</sup> , and it shorten from "的士" which means taxi.

Currently I can think of only a few words which uses this meaning of "的": 打的, 的士, 的哥(male taxi driver), etc。

---

[1] My dictionary says the pronunciation is di2. While in everyday life (in Beijing), what I hear and use is di1.

Comment: And the mainland China borrowed the "的士" as a translation of taxi from Hongkong, they sound more alike in Cantonese.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, the word is borrowed from Cantonese at 80s. Then it gradually be accepted by the other areas in China.

Answer (score 1):

打的 means 打的士, 的士 is transliteration for taxi in Cantonese.

In mainland, we call 打车.

Answer (score 1):

的 is short for 的士, and 的士 is the translation of taxi in pronounce, which comes from Cantonese. The original should be 搭车 or 搭的士. When it comes to mainland China, 搭 changes to 打, so if you need a taxi, you just say 打的.

If you say 打车, we can also understand you need a taxi.